# Publishing newman-reporter-htmlextra reports with Jenkins html publisher fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, newman

I am running [newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman) with [newman-reporter-htmlextra](https://github.com/DannyDainton/newman-reporter-htmlextra) in a `Jenkins pipeline`, generating a html report which I want to publish via the [jenkins html publisher](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).

This is the stage in the pipeline I´m using

```
stage('Newman tests') {
steps() {
    script {
        dir("${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/myproject") {
            sh 'newman run "./Collections/my_collection.postman_collection.json" --reporters cli,junit,htmlextra --reporter-junit-export "newman_result.xml" --reporter-htmlextra-export "newman_result.html"'
            junit "*.xml"
        }
    }
    publishHTML target: [
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: '.',
            reportFiles: 'newman_result.html',
            reportName: 'Newman HTML Reporter'
    ]
}
```

This is running, and creating an entry `Newman HTML Reporter` in my `Jenkins` project.

However, when I open such a report, it is empty, pls check [image: screenshot].

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are accessing the wrong folder when you want to publish your html result.
You are creating your file not in the regular jenkins workspace:

```
dir("${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/myproject") {
    sh 'newman run "./Collections/my_collection.postman_collection.json" --reporters cli,junit,htmlextra --reporter-junit-export "newman_result.xml" --reporter-htmlextra-export "newman_result.html"'
    junit "*.xml"
}
```

After you are leaving the `script{}` you are accessing the original workspace of Jenkins so `reportDir: '.'` is not the same folder where your file is which means no file = no html can be displayed.

You have 3 choices here:

1. You create the file in the regular workspace of Jenkins
2. The HTML Publisher Plugin aims to the correct folder
3. Put the HTML Publisher plugin into the scope of your `dir{}` as you did with your `junit plugin`

To find out easily which folder you are accessing in which scope you can run an `echo pwd`. Do this once in the scope of your `dir{}` and once in the scope of your plugin then it should be clear that the `reportDir` of your plugin is wrong.

Comment: I am facing same issue -- "C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/newman" run "C:/postmancollections/07072021/Test-Collection.postman_collection.json" -r cli,htmlextra --disable-unicode --reporter-htmlextra-export einvoice-test-suite-report.html --reporter-htmlextra-title "Report Test Summary"     and my workspace location is C:\CustomWorkspace and I am able to see html report generated at that location but when I am accessing through jenkins then its empty just same as above

Comment: Michael Kemmerzell , could you please help me with above

Comment: I suggest opening up a new question, not sure if your problem fits to this question

Comment: Michael Kemmerzell, added new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295598/newman-reporter-htmlextra-reports-with-jenkins-html-publisher-not-showing-report