# newman-reporter-htmlextra reports with Jenkins html publisher not showing report in html format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, newman, html-reports-jenkins

I have Postman collections. I am running it through jenkins using below window batch script

```
C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/newman" run "C:/postmancollections/07072021/Test-Collection.postman_collection.json" -r cli,htmlextra --disable-unicode --reporter-htmlextra-export ein-test-suite-report.html --reporter-htmlextra-title "Report Test Summary"
```

my workspace location is C:\CustomWorkspace

In publish html report I have provided index page name as ein-test-suite-report.html

I am able to see html extra report is correctly generated in customworkspace location with name ein-test-suite-report.html

But in jenkins , html report the report is not html , its kind plain report as below attached screenshot

In Custm Worksspace folder , I can see html report as below. I am expecting same we can see in the jenkins

Comment: [This](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/) is the cause of your issue. See more info in the [Following Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins - HTML Publisher Plugin - No CSS is displayed when report is viewed in Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

Comment: thanks @Noam helmer. It helped me

Answer (score 0):

Please use jaiman, internally using the newman and htmlextra

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/jaiman

Comment: Hello @jayanth-bala. I used your product. But it is not possible to send the report to my smtp server because it is impossible to enter authorization data. Could you please share the source code to fix or fix this issue?

Comment: Or post it on github as newman?